# Compare two encrypted passwords condition

Tags: java, json, user-interface, encryption, compare

I am trying to implement a login checker, the function get the credentials from a GUI and compare the users, the the passwords which are encrypted, I don't know how to compare the password given as input with the password in a .json file

The function look like this:

```
public static void checkUsers(String username,String password,String role) {
        for (User user : users) {
            if (Objects.equals(username, user.getUsername()))
            {
                //passwords to be compared
            }
    }
```

The encryption looks like this:

```
  public static String encodePassword(String salt, String password) {
        MessageDigest md = getMessageDigest();
        md.update(salt.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

        byte[] hashedPassword = md.digest(password.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

        // This is the way a password should be encoded when checking the credentials
        return new String(hashedPassword, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
                .replace("\"", ""); //to be able to save in JSON format
    }

    private static MessageDigest getMessageDigest() {
        MessageDigest md;
        try {
            md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("SHA-512 does not exist!");
        }
        return md;
    }
```

Comment: Your passwords are hashed, not encrypted.  You hash the incoming password (with the same salt and stretching) and then compare it to the stored hashed (salted and stretched) original password.  If the hashes are the same then the user entered the correct password.

Comment: Additionally, your passwords are hashed - but not very well.  A single round of unsalted SHA-512 is a particularly poor password hash.  You should be using argon2, bcrypt or PBKDF2.  What you have now is very weak.

Answer (score 0):

For a fixed salt and fixed password, a hashing algorithm will always return a fixed digest.
For each user you need to store the salt and the digest. 
When a user wants to login, you must supply their individual salt. They will calculate their digest and return this to you. Your task is then to compare their returned digest with your stored digest and this will confirm that they have input the correct password.